# How To Solve: Error when reading or editing Project Service Foo/container.googleapis.com: googleapi: Error 403

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, terraform0.12+

I'm new to GCP and I'm trying to enable a number of API's via Terraform.

```
variable "gcp_service_list" {
  description ="Projectof apis"
  type = list(string)
  default = [
    "cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com",
    "serviceusage.googleapis.com"
  ]
}

resource "google_project_service" "gcp" {
  for_each = toset(var.gcp_service_list)
  project = "project-id"
  service = each.key
}
```

but I keep running into the error

```
Error when reading or editing Project Service Foo/compute.googleapis.com: googleapi: Error 403: The caller does not have permission, forbidden
```

What permissions do I need to grant my service account in order for it to be able to do this please?

Comment: Follow this doc for SA, https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#create_service_account

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to enable service APIs in GCP, your user or service account which is being used to run Terraform needs to have the following role:

```
roles/serviceusage.serviceUsageAdmin
```

So, you will either have to grant the user or SA the role above from the console or if you have a Terraform resource to bind roles to users/SA that can be used as well.

From Terraform authentication perspective, if you are using a user account make sure you are properly authenticating from the terminal to GCP using the following command:

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```

If you are using a service account, you will need to specify the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` passing the json key file.

For Terraform authentication reference: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/guides/provider_reference

Comment: Thanks a lot CaioT